# Maximal ideals of $C(X, \mathbb R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $X=(0, 1)$ be the open unit interval and $C(X, \mathbb R)$ be the ring of continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R$. For any $x\in(0, 1)$, let $I(x)=\{f\in C(X, \mathbb R)|f(x)=0\}$. Then which of the following is true?

1. $I(x)$ is prime.
2. $I(x)$ is maximal.
3. Every maximal ideal of $C(X, \mathbb R)$ is equal to $I(x)$ for some $x\in X$.
4. $C(X, \mathbb R)$ is an integral domain

Option 4 isn't true, its well known. Even option 1, 2 also well known. I mean they are true. What troubles me is the option 3. Really I've no idea how to disprove option 3.
I've seen option 3 true for $[0, 1]$, but why here it is not true.

Please help in answer section rather comments. It would be great achievement if I got option 3.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your $\,C(X\,\Bbb R)\,$ have unbounded functions (among others)?

Comment: Yes, it contains 1/x. Please comment in answer section, I want explicit solution about option 3.

Answer (score 1):

Claim 3. is false, as can be seen below.

Define
$$ Z(g)\,:=\,\{x\in(0;1) : g(x)=0\} $$
Let

$$ \forall_{n=1}^\infty\quad f_n(x)\,:=\,
      \sin\left(\frac\pi{2^n\cdot x}\right)  $$
so that
$$ Z(f_n) \,=\, \left\{\frac1{k\cdot 2^n} :\, k\in\Bbb N\right\} $$

are non-empty and decreasing, and

$$ \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty Z(f_n)\,=\,\emptyset $$

Consider the ideal $\,J\,$ generated by the sequence of all functions
$\,f_n.\ $ It is proper and not contained in any $\, I(x)\,$ while it is contained in a maximal ideal (*by a very general theorem*).

That's it.   *Great!*

Comment: Very interesting. Another possible example is to consider the ideal $J$ of all continuous functions of compact support. This ideal is also proper and is not contained in any of the $I(x)$. In particular, if we take a maximal ideal $J'$ containing $J$, we obtain an ideal different from $I(x)$ for any $x \in(0,1)$.

Comment: I would like to add something else. The argument I made always work for non-compact topological manifolds. For compact topological manifolds it's indeed true that the only maximal ideals are these ideals $I(x)$.

Comment: @Hugocito, your comment is perfect. On the other hand, for the sake of the SE audience, I wanted it to start with as specific elementary construction as possible.

Comment: Is there is any theorem regarding this that when a function is maximal depending on domain?

Comment: @DebprasadKundu, "maximal function"? (Should it be "ideal"?). Etc. The q. is not clear to me. Does "domain" mean a topological space or a ring/field of coefficients? Especially, what does "this" mean -- please, avoid pronouns.

Comment: I want to say maximal ideal in the domain like [0, 1]

Comment: Compactness makes a huge difference. In general, one can to study the "zero-sets" of functions, $\,Z(f):=\{x\in X: f(x)=0\}.\,$ and of ideals, $\,Z(J):=\bigcap_{f\in J}Z(f).\,$ The field or ring of coefficients is assumed to be T1, i.e. has 1-element sets closed. Thus the zero-sets are closed.